# GLSL vec2 use as array in float?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, compute-shader, glsles

im trying to make something on shader toy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wsffDN
(original ref: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3dtSD7)
bufferA line 18

i want to know why uv was declared as uv

`vec2 uv = (fragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy*.5) / iResolution.y;`

, but this line

`sceneColor = vec3((uv[0] + stagger) / initpack + 0.05*0., -0, 0.05);`

uv[0] is used as a float

how does this work, and what uv's value become?

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly legal to access the components of any `vec` type (or `mat` type for that matter) with array syntax. You can even use a non-constant array index (well, depending on the GLSL version, but 1.30+ versions allow it). `uv[0]` does exactly what it looks like: access the first element of the vector.